# Laravel eager load resource collection

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

How can I eager load a resource collection relationship? I've made a resource which calls `gravel_pits` relationship

```
class GravelTypeResource extends Resource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'          => $this->id,
            'name'        => $this->name,
            'deleted_at'  => $this->deleted_at,
            'gravel_pits' => $this->gravel_pits,
        ];
    }
}
```

On the model M:M relationship:

```
public function gravel_pits()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\GravelPit');
}
```

And from the API I am getting it back like this:

```
public function index()
{
    return GravelTypeResource::collection(GravelType::all());
}
```

I can eager load it by doing

```
public function index()
{
    return GravelTypeResource::collection(GravelType::with('gravel_pits'));
}
```

which works...but I can't control then what properties of gravel pits I actually want back, instead, eager load fetches them all. Is there a simple workaround to this?

Comment: `::with('author:id,name')` straight from the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Comment: @Kyslk Oh, nifty 5.5 feature!

Comment: Yep :), you did not specify which version so I assumed the :latest

Comment: And if there are 5 models which call it? :) If something changes I would have to change all 5 calls...not really DRY solution :)

Comment: Play with relation definition. Use repository pattern (DO NOT! :D - personally I am against it) try DRYing it somewhere else, use IDE find+replace.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [Resource Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections)

```
GravelTypeResourceCollection::make($collection);
```

and since you can use [load](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#method-load) and [loadMissing](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#method-loadMissing) on eloquent collections you can do this

```
class GravelTypeResourceCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
   $collects = GravelTypeResource::class;

   public function __construct($resource){
        $resource->loadMissing(['gravel_pits']);
        parent::__construct($resource);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a select to get just the fields you want. Just make sure you get the fields that the relationship is based on:

```
return GravelTypeResource::collection(GravelType::with('gravel_pits'=>function($query) {
     $query->select(['id', 'gravel_type_id', 'column3', 'column4']);
});
```